# Any good books on SharePoint interact with JQuery?

Tags: 2007, jquery

Any good books on SharePoint that interact with JQuery?

Comment: I converted this question to a community wiki since it is subjective and can't really be answered definitively. However, I think we could come up with some useful resources. Maybe we could increase the scope to discuss other things besides books?

Comment: Sure, no problem for me but I hope that it will include JQuery books related to both SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010 for the time being. In future, we can add more to it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a book that'll be coming out in early 2012: [Pro SharePoint with jQuery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430240989). I haven't seen another on the subject.

Also, there's a recording of a session I did that you may find interesting. [SharePoint 2010 Client-Side Development with the JSOM and jQuery](http://www.vimeo.com/29124752)

Comment: Any book that is related to SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Pro SharePoint with jQuery is now out

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about books, but i know a good library that makes it really easy to use SharePoint web services : http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'll second Janis' suggestion. While there's no "book" about SPServices, Mark does an excellent job of moderating the forum so there's a huge knowledge base and some great documentation there.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested in a book that cover JQuery library for SharePoint (2007, 2010)?

The JQuery libraries is as follow (non-exhaustive):
Smarttools (http://smarttools.codeplex.com/)
SPServices (http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

I wish to write such book together with the whole community and probably, the book can help to cover some expenses running this Sharepoint.stackexchange.com site.